# App craches without any error or warning

Tags: java, android, xml

I've made a simple android app that contains 2 buttons and a `ListView` all in one activity called `MainActivity`. The `ListView` is populated by an arrayList using an `arrayAdapter`.

I don't have any compilation errors or other errors when launching the app, as you can see in this message board output:

```
Information:Gradle tasks [:app:assembleDebug]
Information:BUILD SUCCESSFUL
Information:Total time: 26.874 secs
Information:0 errors
Information:0 warnings
Information:See complete output in console
```

Here is the complete output from console:

```
Executing tasks: [:app:assembleDebug]

Configuration on demand is an incubating feature.
NDK is missing a "platforms" directory.
If you are using NDK, verify the ndk.dir is set to a valid NDK directory.  It is currently set to C:\Users\Bram\AppData\Local\Android\sdk\ndk-bundle.
If you are not using NDK, unset the NDK variable from ANDROID_NDK_HOME or local.properties to remove this warning.

Incremental java compilation is an incubating feature.

A larger heap for the Gradle daemon is recommended for running jack.

It currently has 1024 MB.
For faster builds, increase the maximum heap size for the Gradle daemon to at least 1536 MB.
To do this set org.gradle.jvmargs=-Xmx1536M in the project gradle.properties.
For more information see https://docs.gradle.org/current/userguide/build_environment.html


A larger heap for the Gradle daemon is recommended for running jack.

It currently has 1024 MB.
For faster builds, increase the maximum heap size for the Gradle daemon to at least 1536 MB.
To do this set org.gradle.jvmargs=-Xmx1536M in the project gradle.properties.
For more information see https://docs.gradle.org/current/userguide/build_environment.html


A larger heap for the Gradle daemon is recommended for running jack.

It currently has 1024 MB.
For faster builds, increase the maximum heap size for the Gradle daemon to at least 1536 MB.
To do this set org.gradle.jvmargs=-Xmx1536M in the project gradle.properties.
For more information see https://docs.gradle.org/current/userguide/build_environment.html

:app:preBuild UP-TO-DATE
:app:preDebugBuild UP-TO-DATE
:app:compileDebugNdk UP-TO-DATE
:app:checkDebugManifest
:app:preReleaseBuild UP-TO-DATE
:app:prepareComAndroidSupportAnimatedVectorDrawable2321Library
:app:prepareComAndroidSupportAppcompatV72321Library
:app:prepareComAndroidSupportDesign2321Library
:app:prepareComAndroidSupportRecyclerviewV72321Library
:app:prepareComAndroidSupportSupportV42321Library
:app:prepareComAndroidSupportSupportVectorDrawable2321Library
:app:prepareDebugDependencies
:app:compileDebugAidl UP-TO-DATE
:app:compileDebugRenderscript UP-TO-DATE
:app:generateDebugBuildConfig UP-TO-DATE
:app:generateDebugResValues UP-TO-DATE
:app:generateDebugResources UP-TO-DATE
:app:mergeDebugResources UP-TO-DATE
:app:processDebugManifest UP-TO-DATE
:app:processDebugResources UP-TO-DATE
:app:generateDebugSources UP-TO-DATE
:app:transformClassesWithPreJackPackagedLibrariesForDebug UP-TO-DATE
:app:transformClassesWithPreJackRuntimeLibrariesForDebug UP-TO-DATE
:app:processDebugJavaRes UP-TO-DATE
:app:transformResourcesWithMergeJavaResForDebug UP-TO-DATE
:app:transformJackWithJackForDebug
:app:compileDebugSources
:app:mergeDebugShaders UP-TO-DATE
:app:compileDebugShaders UP-TO-DATE
:app:generateDebugAssets UP-TO-DATE
:app:mergeDebugAssets UP-TO-DATE
:app:mergeDebugJniLibFolders UP-TO-DATE
:app:transformNativeLibsWithMergeJniLibsForDebug UP-TO-DATE
:app:validateSigningDebug
:app:packageDebug
:app:assembleDebug

BUILD SUCCESSFUL

Total time: 26.874 secs
```

But when I open the app it crashes instantly. what can i do about this?

Here is the code for `MainActivity.java`:

```
package com.mysystem.androidmysystem.mysystem;

import android.os.Bundle;
import android.support.v7.app.AppCompatActivity;
import android.util.Log;
import android.widget.ArrayAdapter;
import android.widget.ListView;

import java.util.ArrayList;

public class MainActivity extends AppCompatActivity {

    ArrayList<String> listItems;

    ListView list;
    ArrayAdapter<String> adapter;

    @Override
    protected void onCreate(Bundle iCicle) {
        super.onCreate(iCicle);
        //listItems=BookingList.getListAsString();      returns ArrayList of strings. this is what I normally use...
        listItems.add("foo");
        listItems.add("boo");
        listItems.add("goo");
        list = (ListView) findViewById(R.id.Bookings);
        Log.d("ITEMLIST","GOT LIST");
        for(String item: listItems)
            Log.d("ITEMLIST",item);
        setContentView(R.layout.activity_main);
        if(listItems!=null) {
            adapter = new ArrayAdapter<String>(this, android.R.layout.simple_list_item_1, listItems);
            list.setAdapter(adapter);
        }

    }
}
```

And here is my `activity_main.xml` file:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<RelativeLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    xmlns:tools="http://schemas.android.com/tools"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent"
    android:paddingBottom="@dimen/activity_vertical_margin"
    android:paddingLeft="@dimen/activity_horizontal_margin"
    android:paddingRight="@dimen/activity_horizontal_margin"
    android:paddingTop="@dimen/activity_vertical_margin"
    tools:context="com.mysystem.androidmysystem.mysystem.MainActivity">

    <TextView
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:textAppearance="?android:attr/textAppearanceLarge"
        android:id="@+id/textView2"
        android:layout_alignParentTop="true"
        android:layout_alignParentLeft="true"
        android:layout_alignParentStart="true" />

    <Button
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:text="Add"
        android:id="@+id/Add"
        android:layout_below="@+id/textView2"
        android:layout_toRightOf="@+id/textView2"
        android:layout_toEndOf="@+id/textView2"
        android:layout_marginLeft="26dp"
        android:layout_marginStart="26dp" />

    <Button
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:text="Edit"
        android:id="@+id/Edit"
        android:layout_alignTop="@+id/Add"
        android:layout_alignRight="@+id/Bookings"
        android:layout_alignEnd="@+id/Bookings"
        android:layout_marginRight="24dp"
        android:layout_marginEnd="24dp" />

    <ListView
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:id="@+id/Bookings"
        android:layout_below="@+id/Edit"
        android:layout_alignParentLeft="true"
        android:layout_alignParentStart="true" />

</RelativeLayout>
```

I'm using a AVD called `API 23 Armeabi-v7a portrait` which seems to run fine normally. What can I do to make the aplication work?

Comment: is there any fatal errors on your logcat ? after your app crashes?

Comment: No. I can't find errors anywhere...

Comment: `listItems` is `null` when you try and add something to it. Change it to `ArrayList<String> listItems = new ArrayList<>();`

Comment: Check your logcat filter.

Comment: where can I find that?

Comment: when you run your app, open Android Monitor of your Android studio. Which will show you run time error in red fonts.

Comment: @Kaushal28 I know that... nothing pops up like I told you

Comment: Remove comment from this: `listItems=BookingList.getListAsString();`

Comment: I have. I just made a quick arraylist to demonstrate it as an SSCCE: http://sscce.org/

Comment: Hey! what was the problem?

Comment: either my emulator was outdated or it was actually his suggestion which worked. which is stange because my emulator could run other apps and I cant understand why his fix would fix anything...

Comment: I've tried initializing list before setContentView, and it is working... Strange!

Comment: yeah IDk anyway it's working now

Comment: hmm.. but I'm 100% sure that wasn't the issue! Enjoy btw

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
@Override
    protected void onCreate(Bundle iCicle) {
        super.onCreate(iCicle);
        //listItems=BookingList.getListAsString();      returns ArrayList of strings. this is what I normally use...
        setContentView(R.layout.activity_main3);
        list = (ListView) findViewById(R.id.Bookings);
        listItems = new ArrayList<>();
        listItems.add("foo");
        listItems.add("boo");
        listItems.add("goo");

        Log.d("ITEMLIST", "GOT LIST");
        for (String item : listItems)
            Log.d("ITEMLIST", item);

        if (listItems != null) {
            adapter = new ArrayAdapter<String>(this, android.R.layout.simple_list_item_1, listItems);
            list.setAdapter(adapter);
        }

    }
```

please update your onCreate with this

Comment: if you've read the comments to the other awnser you can see that this is not the problem...

Comment: @BRHSM you have tried to access listView before setContentView() that is also the reason for the app crash, just try to change your onCreate() with the code I tried.. this may work

Comment: that is not the problem: "Accessing list view before setContentView()"

Comment: @Kaushal28 let him try. PS. accessing a view before rendering it's parent layout to the java class via setContentView() generally gives away a NullPointerException on that view.

Comment: But I think `new ArrayList<>();` has nothing to do with rendering.

Comment: oh you are absolutely right , but " list = (ListView) findViewById(R.id.Bookings);" this thing has everything to do with the rendering.

Comment: Yeah! and it is after set content view in the OP's code!

Comment: should I switch it around?

Answer (score 0):

You've not initialized the your arrayList `listItems` in your `onCreate` method. So add following code in your `onCreate` method, before adding the elements to array list.

```
 listItems = new ArrayList<>();
```

and after initializing this, you can perform your add operation.

Comment: this is not it... Normaly the function above returns an arraylist. I just added the items in like this for the example.